# Change the start button icon in Win10

Tags: windows-10, icons, start-menu

I tried to change the icon in the start button of win10 :

[image]

after downloading a software (start10). That made it really slow and I uninstalled 
it. I want to change that in the CMD or even changing the image (finding the directory).

01) I want to find the image directory of this icon

02) I want to find the command that changes the image

Comment: 1) The icon is embedded in Explorer.exe and/or one of it's libraries.

Comment: 2) You'll have to modify said exe or DLL and replace the bitmap with one you want.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 So it is not possible to alter it?

Comment: See the dupe. :)  If you'd like newer/different answers on the existing duplicate question, consider [placing a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it. Also, if you comment on that question, ensure to include exactly which build of Windows 10 you're trying to use, and which version(s) of Start10 you tried.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Where is the directory of this? Do we know?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Good to know. I tried to check whether there were duplicates and irrelevant things came first.

Comment: I use StartIsBack++: http://startisback.com/ to change it